# Changing connection string dynamically on runtime in WinForms

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I am making Winform dekstop application. I am giving an option in my application that user can select database or set database path. when user select database or database path then connection string should be changed at runtime in APP.config.

Comment: How does SQLEXPRESS relate to MySQL? Or how does another folder help with crashing? I'd rather fix the crashing, since it doesn't happen in normal circumstances. Do explain more about your requirements.

Comment: Sorry for MySql. I am using SQLEXPRESS. Crashing means windows crashing. when user re-install windows then SQLEXPRESS database will be deleted. So i want to store .mdf Database in another drive and user will select database from my application and when user selects the database then in app.config file connection string should be change at runtime.

Comment: Sounds like you simply need to use a transaction.

Comment: Please can you give me any reference??? I m in trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if there is no special needing for connection strings being stored in the standard way in the configuration file,it could be convenient to have a bounch of named `<connectionStrings>` in the standard configuration file and you can enumerate it like this:

```
 foreach (ConnectionStringSettings c in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
    {
        //present the name in some combo etc etc.
    }
```

then the user can select the connection string based on a friendly name.
The configuration file for your app will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    .....
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="connection1" connectionString="Data Source=your connection string 1" />
 <add name="connection2" connectionString="Data Source=your connection string 2" />
 <add name="connection3" connectionString="Data Source=your connection string 3" />
</connectionStrings>
```

....

Comment: Is the path of database file effects connection string??? One database is in my "C:\ProgramFiles\SQLEXPRESS\data\abc.mdf" and same database with same name is in "F:\mydb\abc.mdf" both database have same connection string or not????

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't try and change the connection string in the config at runtime. You could have a set of possible connection strings in the `<connectionStrings>` section of the config file, allow the user to choose what database they want to use and read the appropriate connection from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Is the path of database file effects connection string??? One database is in my "C:\ProgramFiles\SQLEXPRESS\data\abc.mdf" and same database with same name is in "F:\mydb\abc.mdf" both database have same connection string or not????